# 3 Probability Questions: Exponential distribution and Normal

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, exponential-distribution

1. A battery has an average lifespan of $2,000$ hours. It is exponentially distributed. $X \sim \text{exp}(\lambda = \frac{1}{2000})$. $10$ toy cars are using this kind of battery (each has its own) what is the probability **at least** 3 of the toy cars will still drive after $1,700$ hours?
2. You have a machine that creates nails which have in average a diameter of 4 cm. and a standart deviation of $0.1$ cm. Suppose the distribution of the diameter is Normal ($\sim N$) what is the percentage of the nails that will have a diameter over $4.012$
3. a light bulb is distributed exponentially with a lifespan of 1400 hours. The light bulb is inside a street lamp. what is the probability you would need to replace the light bulb 3 times in the next 2000 hours?
   I did not quite understand, $\lambda = \frac{1}{1400}$  and and so the question is what is the probability that it would turn off 3 times? thank you.

My solution:

1. I first calculated what is the probability that a certain car will keep driving after $1,700$ hours. $X \sim exp(\frac{1}{2000})$ . $\lambda = \frac{1700}{2000}$

And so the probability is $\frac{1}{2000} e^{\frac{1700}{2000}} \approx 2.137e(-4)$.  and then what I do is little Bernoulli experiments:

$P(X \geq 3) = 1- P(X \leq 2) = 1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)-P(X=2)$

$P(X=i) = \binom{10}{i} (2.137*10^{-4})^i \cdot (1-(2.137*10^{-4}))^{10-i}$

Did I get it right?

2. $\mu = 4$ and $\sigma = 0.1$  and we need to calculate: $P(X > 4.012) = 1- P(X<4.012) = 1-P(Z < \frac{4.012 - 4}{0.1}) = 1- P(Z < 0.12) = 0.4522 $
   but in the answers there are only:

- 0.454
- 0.546
- 0.884
- 0.116

So which is right? is it the closest one? is it even the right answer (what I got)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

At 1. the probability that a toy car will still drive after (at least) 1,700 hours is $P(X\geq 1700)=1-P(X\leq x)=1-\int_{0}^{1700} \frac{1}{2000} \cdot e^{-\frac{x}{2000}} \, dx=e^{-1700/2000}\approx  0.42741$.

In general it is $P(X\geq x)=e^{-\frac{x}{\lambda}}.$ Then indeed you can use the binomial distribution like you have done.

If I use [this table](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Ersims/ma464/standardnormaltable.pdf) I get   $1-P(X\leq 0.12)=1    -  0.54776=0.45224 \approx0.4522$. This is the same result you have got (rounded to 4 decimal places). So the first option is the closest result.

Comment: Perhaps the diameter is approximate: if you do the calculation with $4.0115\approx 4.012$ the result is the one of the textbook

Comment: @tommik Yes, everything is possible.

Comment: Some people told me I should use Poisson approximation to the first question (exponential dist. ) do you think it's better? how would you do that? I am confused, thank you sir

Comment: @StackOMeow If a random variable is exponentially distributed then I don´t see any reason to use the poisson distribution. You will not get a more accurate result.

Comment: @callculus so you're saying that exponential + binomial is the best option here? thank you sir. I have another question (I am writing it to the original post not to spam this site with another thread) I would appreciate if you will take a look. thank you very much sir. (question 3)

Comment: @StackOMeow *so you're saying that exponential + binomial is the best option here*: Yes. \\ *I am writing it to the original post not to spam this site with another thread* :It is the other way round. If you change your current question then it causes confusion. Feel free to ask a new question in a new post. Just make a copy it.

Comment: @callculus I've added a new question, thank you so much I appreciate it!

Comment: It seems that you have to calculate $X_1+X_2+X_3<2000$. If the sum of the first three bulbs do not hold for 2000 hours, then you have to replace the bulb 3 times.

Comment: @callculus so is it $1400+1400+1400 = 1400*3$ so the probability of it happening is $e^{-3}$ ? thank you

Comment: @StackOMeow No. The sum of n exponential r.v. are gamma distributed, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27908/sum-of-exponential-random-variables-follows-gamma-confused-by-the-parameters). And the sum has to be smaller than 2000.

Comment: @callculus unfortunately we did not learn gamma dist.

Comment: @StackOMeow This was my iidea for 3. My Recomendation: Post 3. as a new question. Maybe you´ll get a more appropiate answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. not very good. The probability

$\mathbb{P}[X>1700]=e^{-\frac{1700}{2000}}\approx 42.74\%$

The rest of the procedure is ok

2. your calculation is ok...I do not know how they approximated the result but your is fine. Chose the closest to yours

Comment: I dont understand it!! :( I knew it was $e^{-\frac{1700}{2000}}$ however I know that $exp$ distribution is $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ so why we don't multiply it by our lambda? $\lambda = \frac{1}{2000}$ ? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For 2), you can derive it from the definition of Normal rvs. If $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then (set $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$, and if $x=s, z=\frac{s-\mu}{\sigma}=t$)
$$
P(X>s) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} \int_{s}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}} dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{t}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}dz = \Phi(t) = \Phi(\frac{s-\mu}{\sigma})
$$
where $s=4.012$.